# How do I fix a "No instance of overloaded function" error with cin.getline?

Tags: c++, getline

```
string add_text()
{
    const int string_size(30);
    string add_string;
    cin.getline (add_string,string_size,'\n');
    return add_string;
}
```

When I compile the program with the function above, I get an error. Note that I am using `using namespace std;` earlier in the program. If it helps I am using Code Blocks and have also tried compiling the program using the Visual Studio 11 Professional Beta.

**The Error:**

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Code_Blocks\test_12\main.cpp|32|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> ::getline(std::string&, const int&, char)'|
```

Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling [std::istream::getline(char *, streamsize)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) - you can see it requires a `char *` instead of the `std::string` you're passing.

Use [std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&, char)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead, like so:

```
getline(cin, add_string, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

`istream::getline` doesn't take a `std::string` as parameter, but a `char*`. You can fix it by calling the function correctly.

So, provided you know the max size of the line:

```
char buff[256]; //or whatever length
cin.getline (buff,string_size,'\n');
string add_string(buff);
```

Comment: This is also a very nice answer, it is interesting that you were thinking of the maximum size of the line which I didn't of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use member `.getline()`s, but global [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Member `.getline()`s can only use `char *` as buffer, while `std::getline()` can use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.getline` is a member function.  As such, it is not overloaded to account for every possible type in existence.  So, developers overload the global version (i.e., `std::getline`).